# Adding Links to grid cells(autogenerated gridview using C#), and getting information based on what user clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I autogenerate a column of values from a List UserID; which is generated using stored Oracle procedure, which takes input string(if...id Like "%string%" return refcursor) ; So the UserId list looks like that in the grid:

> UserID
>
> 1111555
>
> 2222111
>
> 3331113
>
> ...

Now based on search parameters lenth, this column migh be from 1 record to 10(if UserID.count>10 then error message),so everytime we see different values in the grid

My questrion is how to put links on these autogenerated UserID's(which are in cells) that when user cliks on one of them I could get the selected id(1111555) and using it show another grid to the user:)

It's probably very simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle the `OnRowDataBound` event as so:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          // Display the company name in italics.
          e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<a href=\"page.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "\">"+e.Row.Cells[0].Text+"</a>";

        }
}
```

Where the UserID is the first column in the grid (Cell[0]). Here's the markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        allowpaging="true"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: well we have put a link on our list of values: 111...,2222...,333... but how to get their values to the method  onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" , I mean How do I send chosen value(1111555) there?

Comment: @Kasun could you perhaps explain my next question about sending values to methods?